# Python String question using string libraries

Tags: python

Consider the pattern `%at%` where `%` can have zero or any number of occurrences of an alphabetical character. For example, the string `"BAT, FAT, LATER, HABIT" has three words that match the pattern.

How can this be done in Python?

Comment: Still not crystal, so in your example HAT CAT MATTER, we should be able to just print uhm 3? since `AT` came thrice?

Comment: @santosh Have you tried to code it?

Comment: @planet260 i am not able to get the logic

Comment: @user5173426 yes AT came thrice so i should print 3

Comment: Okay, does it have to be a pattern or just a searching for a substring?

Comment: what if you try  `len("EX:BAT,FAT,LATER,HABIT".split("at".upper())) - 1`

Comment: @user5173426 it is just pattern

Comment: @santoshkumar I posted an answer for it already.

Comment: @santoshkumar did any of the answers posted below help solve your problem? If so, you may mark the one that you wish to, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

```
import re

str_list = ['BAT', 'FAT', 'LATER', 'HABIT']    
counter = 0

for strr in str_list:
    if re.search('at', strr, re.IGNORECASE):
        counter += 1   
print(counter)
```

OUTPUT:

> 3

Answer (score 0):

```
mylist = ['BAT', 'FAT', 'LATER', 'HABIT']

count = 0
for pattern in mylist:
    if 'at' in pattern.lower():
        count = count + 1    
print(count)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Counter to make the codes shorter:

```
from collections import Counter
str_list = ['BAT', 'FAT', 'LATER', 'HABIT']
my_counter = Counter('at' in word.lower() for word in str_list)
# 3
print(my_counter[True])
```